# Unable to get key value from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am unable to get key and values from below json object and getting an error as mentioned below.

**Edit :**
I need to find the keys dynamically(in this case Day and Counts) and then get values based on mapping these keys.

I have tried this :

```
// json is the json object
var columns = Object.keys($.parseJSON(json)[0]);                       
//var columns = Object.keys($.parseJSON(json)["Table"]);    
var result = JSON.parse(json).map(function (o) {
    return columns.map(function (key) {
        return o[key];
    });
});
```

**JSON object :**

```
"{
  "Table": [
    {
      "Day": "Jun 18",
      "Counts": 3
    },
    {
      "Day": "Jun 19",
      "Counts": 5
    },
    {
      "Day": "Jun 20",
      "Counts": 8
    },
    {
      "Day": "Jun 21",
      "Counts": 15
    }]
}"
```

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Your JSON is an object, therefore, it does not have `map` function, which is for arrays.

Comment: yea I am also getting error on map also, how to get these values then?

Comment: What do you want to get. Please specify the expected output.

Comment: I want keys : Day and Counts and their related values as I have tried using map ..

Comment: How do you define than *json object* in your code? I ask it because with that double-quotes around, it may not be a json object but a string.

Comment: @SunilKumar your definition is not accurate. Please, edit your post and write the JSON expected as the output. Just write it, it'll be clear for everyone then.

Comment: I have updated my question, pl check edit part..

Comment: That is still unclear. Write down some JSON or the only answers you'll get will be unclear too. You've shown the input, just show the output. What is so hard about that?

Comment: sry @sjahan, may be my question is not so clear, pl see the answer of user3808826..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your json, code should be like this

```
var columns = Object.keys($.parseJSON(json).Table[0]);                       
var result = JSON.parse(json).Table.map(function (o) {
    return columns.map(function (key) {
        return o[key];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Just two lines

```
 

    
 

    const test = (json) => {
              const obj = JSON.parse(json);
              const keys = Object.keys(obj.Table[0]);
              const values = obj.Table.map(row=>_.values(row));
              return {keys, values}
            }
```

## output

```
{ 
  keys: [ 'Day', 'Counts' ],
  values: 
   [ [ 'Jun 18', '3' ],
     [ 'Jun 19', '5' ],
     [ 'Jun 20', '8' ],
     [ 'Jun 21', '15' ] ] 
}
```

Comment: I wanted 2 different results one for keys one for values in 2 different var